# Connecting to database with PDO in php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've written this small class for my database connections in my project:

```
 <?php
    class DatabaseUtility{

        private $dsn, $username, $password, $database, $pdo;

        public function __construct($host = 'localhost', $username = 'root', $password = '', $database){
            $this->dsn = "mysqli:dbname=$database;host:$host";
            $this->username = $username;
            $this->password = $password;
            $this->database = $database;
        }

        public function connect(){
            try{
                $this->pdo = new PDO($this->dsn,$this->username,$this->password,null);
                $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
            } catch(PDOException $err){
                die($err->getMessage());
            }
        }

        public function prepareStatment($query){
            $this->pdo->prepare($query);
        }

    }
?>
```

And this is how i'm using it:

```
<?php
    require 'DatabaseUtility.php';
    $db = new DatabaseUtility('localhost','root','','apex');
    $db->connect();
    $statment = $db->prepareStatment("Select offer_id from offer_images where img_id = :img_id");

?>
```

But i'm getting the following error:

```
Could not find driver
```

I'm new to PDO stuff so please do guide me what i'm doing wrong? Is this method okay for a secure and fast database activity?

**Update:**
I'm now using these lines of code to use my DatabaseUtility class but got an error:

```
 <?php
        require 'DatabaseUtility.php';
        $id= 25;
        $db = new DatabaseUtility('localhost','root','','apex');
        $db->connect();
        $statment = $db->prepareStatment("Select offer_id from offer_images where img_id = :img_id");
       $statment->bindParam("img_id", $id ,PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $statment->execute();
        print_r($statment);
    ?>
```

Error is:

```
call to a member function bindParam() on a non-object in this line:
$statment->bindParam("img_id", $id ,PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Comment: It seems like you dont have installed PHP PDO module on your server

Comment: Is he PDO driver enabled in your server's php.ini?

Comment: I'm using it on Local host and as far as i have checked it is enabled in PHP.ini file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are not returning anything in your `prepareStatment()` method.

```
public function prepareStatment($query){
    return $this->pdo->prepare($query);
}
```

This is the reason  `$statment = $db->prepareStatment("Select offer_id from offer_images where img_id = :img_id");` was returning false.

Answer (score 3):

So it seems like you're mixing [`MYSQL`](https://www.mysql.com/) as database with the MYSQL API's in PHP  e.g. [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), [`mysqli_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or `mysql_*`.

You use `PDO` as API to connect to your MYSQL database. But you have a few little errors in your [connection](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php) string:

```
                        //vvvvv < -- > vvvvvvvvv
$this->dsn = "mysqli:host=$host;dbname:$database";
                 //^ ^^^^ < - > ^^^^^^^ must be a equal sign
                 //| Your database is MYSQL so remove the i
```

Comment: Nice catch with the `=`

Comment: what about not assigning the `prepare` to a variable or returning it `$stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($query);` ?

Comment: @SubhanAhmed See my updated answer, missed one thing. You had host and dbname switched! Now everything should work perfectly fine

Comment: Sorry i havn't got you.

Comment: Please answer my question now as i've mentioned a new problem

Comment: @SubhanAhmed Also put your prepare statement in a try and catch block and see if you get any errors.

Comment: call to a member function bindParam() on a non-object  this is what i get